# Can't use multiple extensions with "find"

Tags: scripts, delete, find

I write a script to delete all types of archives from the last weak. My script is this and it works:
`list=$(find $1 -name "*zip." -mtime -7) for x in $list do rm -i "$x" done`

The problem is when I try to add another type of archive like: `list=$(find $1 -name "*zip." , -name "*.tar" -mtime -7)` . It works just for .tar archives.

Comment: And https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15308/how-to-use-find-command-to-search-for-multiple-extensions

Comment: I tried to use this "\( -name "*.zip" -o -name "*.tar" \), but i have to put the result in a variable I can't write : ```list= $(find $1 \( -name "*.zip" -o -name "*.tar" \) -mtime -7)```

Comment: If I write like that i have this error: find: (-name: no such file or directory.

Comment: Why can't you write: `list=$(find "$1" \( -name "*.zip" -o -name "*.tar" \) -mtime -7)` ?? This is the correct way to do it!

Comment: Please be aware that adding filenames to a variable to use that in a `for` loop is very bad practice ...

Comment: I m new to this and I thought this is a good way, I don't know many ways now. I'll practice and I'll improve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
find "$1" -type f \( -name \*.zip -o -name \*.tar \)
```

If you want to store find result into a variable, use command substition.

```
result=$(find "$1" -type f \( -name \*.zip -o -name \*.tar \) -mtime -7)
```

Comment: And If i have to put the find result in a variable?

Comment: @Christina Then you can use your method— command substition.

Comment: My problem is that my script works for one type of archive, but find doesn't work if I put 2 types. I used the last think you wrote, but when I do this It deletes all archives no matter what date they have

Comment: @Christina What do you mean doesn't work ? Does it find the second types/extension ?

Comment: it is because the -mtime only applies to -name *tar, not to *.zip if you don't add brackets.

Comment: what @pLumo said it's what I mean when I say " It doesn't work". And I don t know how to add brackets properly if I have to put the result in a variable too

Comment: the brackets like you posted in **your** comment above is correct.

Comment: @pLumo yes It is, I think It didn't work earlier because I used " , " instead of "-o". Thank you so much to both of you!!!